# Paypal checkout for marketplace: how to create recurrig payment in the seller connected account

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-marketplaces

Paypal checkout for marketplace how to create recurrig payment in the seller connected account

How to create one-time and recurring payment in the seller connected account

Admin PayPal Account is collect only platform fee and create Payment in the seller account directly

is there any solution to create payment in the seller account

I am trying to create recurrring payment in the seller account but it is not working for me

I am trying to create Subscription in the seller connected account but it create subscription in main Admin PayPal account, Admin account in collect only platform fee

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Subscriptions API does not support platform_fee, and does not support third party API calls using a client_id+secret that is different from the account that will receive the payment.

To use the PayPal Subscriptions API, you must first obtain the client_id+secret of the account that is going to receive payments. Then you can use that information to first create a plan_id, and then provide a Subscription button/checkout using that plan_id in the `createSubscription` callback function.

Comment: then how can we collect platform commission in the main PayPal account and is there any option to create a subscription in the seller account? @Preston PHX

Comment: The above describes how to create the subscription using the seller's API credentials. There is no option for platform fees or commissions with the PayPal Subscription API.

Comment: okay, thanks for the confirmation,
is there possible to create a subscription in the seller account using the seller merchant id or seller email id instead of collecting client_id+secret if it is not possible then how can we get this? @Preston PHP

Comment: Ask the seller to obtain them from a rest APP at https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live